# Print one string from arrays of strings

Tags: arrays, string, assembly, irvine32

How to make arrays of string in assembler and work with them?

I try:

```
arrayOfWords BYTE "BICYCLE", "CANOE", "SCATEBOARD", "OFFSIDE", "TENNIS"
```

and after I want to print second word, but its dont work

```
    mov edx, offset arrayOfWords[2]
    call WriteString
```

but He print me all world.

Comment: If you use Kip Irvine's library, please tag the question with [irvine32] and [masm].

Comment: irvine http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Fabout.htm

Comment: Then click on "edit" and add under "Tags" [masm] and [irvine32] (without brackets).  After that you get some examples from me me to copy and paste ;-)

Comment: Ok. I edit my post.. I am making hangman game in irvine 32.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arrayOfWords` is not an array, not even a variable. It's just a label that tells the assembler where it can find something, in this case a bunch of characters. Irvine's [`WriteString`](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Firvinelib%2Fwritestring.htm) expects a **null-terminated** bunch of characters as string. There are two methods to treat that bunch of characters as string array.

1. Search the memory for the right address to the desired string. At every null begins a new string.

   ```
   INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

   .DATA
   manyWords BYTE "BICYCLE", 0
       BYTE "CANOE", 0
       BYTE "SCATEBOARD", 0
       BYTE "OFFSIDE", 0
       BYTE "TENNIS", 0
       BYTE 0                              ; End of list
   len equ $ - manyWords

   .CODE
   main PROC

       mov edx, 2                          ; Index
       call find_str                       ; Returns EDI = pointer to string

       mov edx, edi
       call WriteString                    ; Irvine32: Write astring pointed to by EDX

       exit                                ; Irvine32: ExitProcess
   main ENDP

   find_str PROC                           ; ARG: EDX = index

       lea edi, manyWords                  ; Address of string list

       mov ecx, len                        ; Maximal number of bytes to scan
       xor al, al                          ; Scan for 0

       @@:
       sub edx, 1
       jc done                             ; No index left to scan = string found
       repne scasb                         ; Scan for AL
       jmp @B                              ; Next string

       done:
       ret
   find_str ENDP                           ; RESULT: EDI pointer to string[edx]

   END main
   ```
2. Build an array of pointers to the strings:

   ```
   INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

   .DATA
   wrd0 BYTE "BICYCLE", 0
   wrd1 BYTE "CANOE", 0
   wrd2 BYTE "SCATEBOARD", 0
   wrd3 BYTE "OFFSIDE", 0
   wrd4 BYTE "TENNIS", 0

   pointers DWORD OFFSET wrd0, OFFSET wrd1, OFFSET wrd2, OFFSET wrd3, OFFSET wrd4

   .CODE
   main PROC

       mov ecx, 2                          ; Index
       lea edx, [pointers + ecx * 4]       ; Address of pointers[index]
       mov edx, [edx]                      ; Address of string
       call WriteString

       exit                                ; Irvine32: ExitProcess
   main ENDP

   END main
   ```

BTW: As in other languages, the index starts at 0. The second string would be index = 1, the third index = 2.

Comment: `lea edi, manyWords` --> how would I do this in nasm or fasm?

Comment: @Jodimoro: NASM: `lea edi, [manyWords]` or `mov edi, manyWords`..I guess in FASM it is identical. I'm unsure wether and how `irvine32.lib`  works in NASM or FASM. It doesn't work in Linux anyway. If you ask a new question, I'll work on it ;-)

Comment: @Jodimoro: Why not what? I don't understand the question.

Comment: @Jodimoro: After the operation, `EDI` should contain the address of `manyWords`. `mov edi, [manyWords]` would load the value, not the address. `mov edi, manyWords` loads the address. Casually speaking, `lea edi, [manyWords]` calculates the address of the value [manyWords]. MASM is different manyWords without brackets is the value and "OFFSET manyWords" expresses the address. I prefer `LEA` because it can calculate the address of local variables at runtime. But this isn't relevant in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
arrayOfWords BYTE "BICYCLE", "CANOE", "SCATEBOARD", "OFFSIDE", "TENNIS"
```

is just  another way to write

```
arrayOfWords BYTE "BICYCLECANOESCATEBOARDOFFSIDETENNIS"
```

and this is far from being an array.
Furthermore `mov edx, offset arrayOfWords[2]` is not an array indexing.
Brackets in assembly are used to denote an [addressing mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode), not array indexing.
That's why I can't stop stressing out to **NOT**<sup>1</sup> use the syntax `<symbol>[<displacement>]` (your `arrayOfWords[2]`) - it is a very silly and confusing way to write `[<symbol> + <displacement>]` (in your case `[arrayOfWords + 2]`).

You can see that `mov edx, OFFSET [arrayOfWords + 2]` (that in my opinion is clearer written as  `mov edx, OFFSET arrayOfWords + 2` since the instruction is not accessing any memory) is just loading `edx` with the address of the *C* character in *BICYCLE* (the third char of the big string).

MASM has a lot of high-level machinery that I never bothered learning, but after a quick glance at the manual linked in the footnotes, it seems that it has no high-level support for arrays.
That's a good thing, we can use a cleaner assembly.

An array of strings is not a continuous block of strings, it is a continuous block of *pointers* to strings.
The strings can be anywhere.

```
arrayOfWords  DWORD  OFFSET strBicycle, 
                     OFFSET strCanoe,
                     OFFSET strSkateboard,
                     OFFSET strOffside,
                     OFFSET strTennis

strBicycle    BYTE "BICYCLE",0
strCanoe      BYTE "CANOE", 0
strSkateboard BYTE "SKATEBOARD", 0
strOffside    BYTE "OFFSIDE", 0
strTennis     BYTE "TENNIS", 0
```

Remember: the nice feature of arrays is constant access time; if the strings were to be put all together we'd get a more compact data structure but no constant access time since there'd be no way to know where a string starts but by scanning the whole thing.
With pointers we have constant access time, in general, we require all the elements of an array to be homogeneous, like the pointers are.

To load the address of the *i-th*<sup>2</sup> string in the array we simply read the *i-th* pointer.
Suppose *i* is in `ecx` then

```
mov edx, DWORD PTR [arrayOfWords + ecx*4]
call writeString
```

since each pointer is four bytes.

If you want to read the byte *j* of the string *i* then, supposing *j* is in `ebx` and *i* in `ecx`:

```
mov esi, DWORD PTR [arrayOfWords + ecx*4]
mov al, BYTE PTR [esi + ebx]
```

The registers used are arbitrary.

---

<sup>1</sup> Despite what Microsoft writes in its [MASM 6.1 manual](http://people.sju.edu/~ggrevera/arch/references/MASM61PROGUIDE.pdf):

> **Referencing Arrays**
>   Each element in an array is referenced with an index number, beginning with zero. The array index appears in brackets after the array name, as in
>
> `array[9]`
>
> Assembly-language indexes differ from indexes in high-level languages, where the index number
>   always corresponds to the element’s position. In C, for example, array[9] references the array’s
>   tenth element, regardless of whether each element is 1 byte or 8 bytes in size.
>   In assembly language, an element’s index refers to the number of bytes between the element and the start of the array.

<sup>2</sup> Counting from zero.

Comment: Thank you a lot. This is best explane what I read.. :) New I would try to solve my problem like that. I am making hangman game for my university project. Its 30% of my mark.